# Equation spacing changes depending on whether leqno or regno is used

Tags: spacing, equations

I'd like to change from using left aligned (leqno) numbering/tagging to right (reqno) aligned.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,11pt, oneside, leqno, ngerman]{report}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}



\begin{document}
\section*{5. Gedämpfte Schwingung}


Für eine gedämpfte Schwingung muss (\ref{10}) um ein Dämpfungsglied erweitert werden. Dieses hat die Form:

\begin{equation} \label{22}
2 \ast \delta \ast \dot{x}
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\smallskip
Daher ergibt sich als neue Differentialgleichung:

\begin{equation} \label{23}
\ddot{x}_{(t)} + 2 \delta \ast \dot{x} + x_{(t)} \ast \omega^{2}_{(0)} = 0 
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\smallskip
Wenn wir diese nun lösen, erhalten wir: 

\begin{equation} \label{24}
x_{(t)} = {x}_{(0)} e^{\delta \ast t}(\cos(\omega \ast t) + \frac{\delta}{\omega} \ast \sin(\omega \ast t))
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\smallskip
Daher ergibt sich für \begin{math}\tau\end{math} 

\begin{equation} \label{25}
\tau = \tau_{(0)} \ast \sqrt{1 + \frac{\Lambda^{2}}{4 \ast \pi^{2}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: leqno]

If I now change to reqno the spacing is different:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,11pt, oneside, reqno, ngerman]{report}
\usepackage[reqno]{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}



\begin{document}
\section*{5. Gedämpfte Schwingung}


Für eine gedämpfte Schwingung muss (\ref{10}) um ein Dämpfungsglied erweitert werden. Dieses hat die Form:

\begin{equation} \label{22}
2 \ast \delta \ast \dot{x}
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\smallskip
Daher ergibt sich als neue Differentialgleichung:

\begin{equation} \label{23}
\ddot{x}_{(t)} + 2 \delta \ast \dot{x} + x_{(t)} \ast \omega^{2}_{(0)} = 0 
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\smallskip
Wenn wir diese nun lösen, erhalten wir: 

\begin{equation} \label{24}
x_{(t)} = {x}_{(0)} e^{\delta \ast t}(\cos(\omega \ast t) + \frac{\delta}{\omega} \ast \sin(\omega \ast t))
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\smallskip
Daher ergibt sich für \begin{math}\tau\end{math} 

\begin{equation} \label{25}
\tau = \tau_{(0)} \ast \sqrt{1 + \frac{\Lambda^{2}}{4 \ast \pi^{2}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: reqno]

How do I prevent this from happening? Or fix/change it manually to have the same spacing?

Thanks in advance

Jannis

Comment: note you should never have a blank line before a display equation.

Comment: also it is good practice not to use numbers in `\label` latex will work correctly but it is confusing when looking at the source if equation 24 has `\label{20}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why not? I know, but the paper is relatively short and I ensured they correspond.

Comment: if you leave a blank line then tex generates a spurious paragraph with an empty line of text) it looks like vertical space but is not, and is for example not dropped at a page break)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tex has two sets of skips `\abovedisplayskip` and `\abovedisplayshortskip`  the latter is used if the last line of the paragraph above the display is short and does not overlap the formula so the formula can be moved up to "slot into the gap".

With `leqno` the short skip is never used as the equation number is always at the left.

You could set the two lengths to the same value, and similarly for the `\belowdisplay[short]skip`

```
\abovedisplayshortskip=\abovedisplayskip
\belowdisplayshortskip=\belowdisplayskip
```

They **have** to be put after `\begin{document}`